# What's the most armor I can give a vehicle at character creation?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, vehicles, armor

In SR4, there's a rule that you can't get an item over rating 6 or availability 12 at chargen:
"no piece of gear purchased at character creation can haev a rating higher than 6 or an Availability higher than 12." (SR4A 86.)

In Arsenal, the Armor vehicle modification can have an Armor Rating from 1-20, or twice the vehicle's body. The armor rating *replaces* the vehicle's stock armor.

One of the guys in our game thinks I shouldn't be able to get a vehicle with an Armor rating higher than 6. What gives? Many of the stock vehicles in the core book have more than 6 Armor; most armored gear, like an Armored Vest, can also go above 6.

Am I allowed to upgrade my vehicle's armor above 6, or not? What's the most armor I can give a vehicle during character creation?

Comment: I had the obvious answer of "yeah, you can, duh", until I realized about the "no gear over Rating 6" rule, which I never considered as applying to vehicle armor. Now I have a serious doubt. So good question, will be interested to see an answer on whether the "Max Rating 6" applies to Vehicle armor or not.

Comment: Another good question would be 'Can a starting character have vehicle mods AT ALL?' - given that Arsenal describes the rolls one needs to make to mod-up a vehicle. I know some GMs tend to rule only stock guns and vehicles are permissible when starting-out.

Answer (score 2):

**You can get a vehicle with armor higher than 6.**

SR4A p86 quote:

> All gear is subject to gamemaster approval—just because you can 
>   purchase something doesn’t mean you should be allowed to get it at 
>   the start of the game. Finally, no piece of gear purchased at
>   character  creation can have a rating higher than 6 or an Availability
>   higher than  12 (for more information, see Availability & Buying Gear,
>   p. 312).

Now, let's take a look at page 69

> Gear Ratings Some gear has ratings, beginning at 1 and increasing with
>   the capability and sophistication of the item. In addition to cost,
>   gear usually has  an Availability, which determines how readily and
>   quickly the item  can be obtained.

and 311, which treads on the same topic:

> Device Rating: The Device rating determines the overall quality and 
>   effectiveness of an item. When the item provides a bonus to certain
>   types of tests, apply the rating as a dice pool bonus to the  test.
>   For example, a medkit with a Device rating of 3 would add  three dice
>   to First Aid Tests, while a medkit with a rating of 5 adds  ive dice.
>   In some cases, a Device rating may be used in place of a  character’s
>   skill, such as a medkit that is hooked up to a patient  and allowed to
>   work without a character’s supervision.

The gear rating limit of 6 can be interpreted in two ways:

1. Device/gear rating limit of 6
2. Limit of 6 on every of the gear's
   attributes, which are accidentally called ratings as well (SR4A
   p310).

In second case, I'd argue that availability is a rating, too, and one is therefore limited to availability 6 at chargen (and incidentally Restricted Gear is a useless quality). While SR4 have multiple cases of bad design, this would be a little over the top.

In first case, you're fine, since the vehicle doesn't have rating.